# Turning off dashed lines on object imported from sketchup

Tags: 3d-view

I've begun importing from sketchup and my model groups have wire ( dashed line ) going back to the datum origin. They don't show in final renders  but is there any way I can turn off their displaying as they get in the way?

[image: image of building with wire going to origin]

this is the same no matter if I use Blendup, but its the same via Collada, and 3DS.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23422/lines-while-importing-dae-files and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/removing-dotted-assist-lines-problem-only-occurs-when-appending

Comment: also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33242/what-are-these-block-dotted-lines/33243#33243

Comment: thanks guys, don't know enough to use the right search terms