# I just imported a COLLADA from OnShape and there are now a bunch of dotted lines from each mesh to the origin

Tags: import, collada, dae

A) Is this a problem/did I do something wrong?

b) How can I get rid of these lines in the viewport?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179366/88681

Comment: Duplicate of [lines while importing .dae files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23422/lines-while-importing-dae-files)